# Electrolytic capacitor lifetime in neon discharge circuit

Tags: power-supply

About a hundred years ago my dad kept me fascinated with his amateur radio "hobby" and built a simple neon flasher with a cap, resistor, and the neon bulb. That flasher box lasted for the longest time until it "got lost" - in kid terms.

Today I'm using a 2000 hour rated 1 μF cap, a 680 kΩ resistor and about 110 V generated with a small HV PS.  My scope shows about a 78 V high when the neon fires and a low voltage of about 60 V or so. So, this cap is subject to about a 2 Hz flash rate with a "ripple" lets call it, of about 18 V. The measured current in this DC loop is about 0.5 mA.

With these parameters, how is the electrolytic cap's life affected? Do these caps "like" this "ripple activity" or do they prefer a smooth DC potential?

Comment: Why don't you use a polyethylene 1 uF capacitor and quit worrying about how long your electrolytic is going to last?

Comment: thanks for the tip..

Comment: You might want to try some other glow-tube circuits such as an astable multivibrator (like a RR-crossing blinker), ring counter, etc. See https://www.homemade-circuits.com/neon-lamps-working-and-application-circuits/ , or the *GE Glow Lamp Manual*, https://archive.org/details/GE_Neon_Lamps_1965/ . Have fun with plasma-state electronics! BTW, I was amazed that a CK722 transistor, audio transformer and single B2M *selenium* photocell could oscillate and light an NE-2 lamp,

Answer (score 0):

Ripple current is an important factor that can limit the life of an electrolytic capacitor but, from your word description of the circuit I reckon the ripple current may be thousands of times greater than the average current of 0.5 mA.

For instance, when the neon "fires" it will take a short surge of current that might be several amps to dozens of amps. That surge will continue until the neon stops illuminating. I'm thinking here that using an electrolytic may be a poor idea if you want it to last ten years.

I would recommend using a polyethylene capacitor of the correct voltage rating (i.e. higher than your power supply voltage plus 20% or 30% margin). Lifetimes of these parts will be in the hundreds of thousands of hours: -

[image]

[The one above](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/440/e_WIMA_SMD_PET-1139826.pdf) is a surface mount part but you can get leaded types.

Answer (score 0):

The abs. value of the average current through the e-cap can't be any greater than 110VDC/680kΩ = 160uA, obviously. RMS will be higher. A simulation gives an RMS current of 750uA

[image]

Ripple current is mostly an issue because of self-heating of large power supply capacitors through the resistive component of their impedance. As you may know, the life of the capacitor is *strongly* dependent on the temperature. 2000 hrs is the life of a cheap capacitor at elevated temperature, and we expect life to double for every 10°C below the specified temperature. For example, the cheapest 1uF/200V capacitor Digikey lists is a Nichicon part with 16mA rated ripple current. At 0.75mA you're at about 5% of that. Life is specified as 2000 hrs at 105°C.

It's quite likely that will still be operating perfectly in 2033 and even 2043 with that 105°C cap at normal room temperature. Seems there's a lot of FUD surrounding electrolytic capacitors. The neon has a limited life, and the large 20mA-ish pulses may shorten its life somewhat. As the neon ages, its trigger voltage will tend to increase (if memory serves) and your relatively low 110VDC source may no longer trigger it. A source derived from 120VAC mains will be more like 160VDC (of course there are more safety issues with the latter, especially if you don't use an isolation transformer).